# D3 v5 unable to get bar chart section key name

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, bar-chart

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-kare-rtice)

I'm trying to get the selection name and cannot find the substitute for d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key as used in [this example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_hover.html)

```
.on("mouseover", (d, i, nodes) => {
    const subgroupName = d3.select(nodes).datum().key; //d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
    console.log(subgroupName);
  })
```

I tried using the 3rd node param in the mouse over function but not able to get the key and index in datum()

this.prentNode selects the top g however nodes are the rect inside the g. trying to find way to select the g element

How to get the selection key from data

Comment: I'm getting blank screen from the CodeSandbox. Also, `d3.select(this)` should get you the `rect` object that should have a key and index.

Answer (score -1):

```
d3.select(nodes[i].parentNode).datum().key
```

this solved the problem for me as nodes[i] would be considered as this.